# Cannot create widget in Android Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to create edittext using Java in bottom fragment class based on input that is to be passed from top fragment. But when I type

```
Button add_submit = new Button(this);
```

I get error for the this for parameter. However I can use this code in MainActivity.java.

Why is this so? What is causing the error and how to fix it?

The following are the complete code for the class

```
package com.test.gpacalc;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class AddActivityBottom extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_add_bottom,container,false);
        return view;
    }

    public void createAddInput(String number_of_subjects){
        Button add_submit = new Button(this);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Button constructor requires context as an argument. Fragment doesn't implement it, activity does. try `new Button(getActivity())`